# The unbiasedness of OLS estimator under random, zero-mean and independent regressors

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, unbiased-estimator

Consider the following regression model: y=x'β+z'γ+e, where x and z are p×1 and q×1 zero-mean random vectors consist of regressors respectively, e is the error term, x, z and e are independent of each other.

I wonder if I omit the vector z and regress y on x, will the estimator of β still be unbiased(suppose the design matrix is full-rank)? If E(x'beta_hat)=x'β for reduced-rank design matrix?

My guess is 'Yes'. Because I think the omitted z can be viewed as a part of the new error term e'=z'y+e due to its zero-mean and independent properties. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Thank you:)@ecnmetrician